# CloudFormation without snapshot

Tags: amazon-ami, packer, aws-cloudformation

Cloudformation created a template for us which specifies both the AMI instance to start from, and also the snapshot ID of that AMI instance.

We create our base AMI instance with Packer, which reports the AMI instance it creates, but does not report the snapshot associated - we find that in the Amazon UI.

Can the Cloudformation template be modified so it does not specify the snapshot ID?  Can you give an example of the stanza?

Comment: I've never specified the snapshot ID in a CloudFormation EC2 template. I only set the `ImageId` in `Properties`. Have you tried removing the snapshot ID from the template and creating a new instance?

Comment: @PatrickLee.  Yes I have.  We use an Ansible playbook which references the CloudFormation template.  It fails if I remove the snapshot ID.  It spits a large listing of what appear to be details of the intended creation, but no obvious error messages.  I am approaching the problem from a different angle now, and will trying this step again soon.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! For example, something like this would work:

```
  "Resources": {
    "someEC2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "...valid_ami_id...",
        "InstanceType": "m3.medium",
        "KeyName": "...",
        "Monitoring": "false",
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            ...
          }
        ],
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
            "Ebs": {
              "VolumeSize": 10
            }
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    }
```